# How to next() until no further items, then return to original state of listed items

Tags: jquery

I am almost there with the script I am writing, but once I reach the end of the list, I need a way to know that I have reached the end and that next button needs to take me back to the list and add .itemBox and itemHeader classes back to their respective elements. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>var itemText = $('div.itemDescription').children().not('h3');
        //hide item text when page loads.
        itemText.hide();
        //set all div.itemDescriptions to have Aria-expanded attribute set to false.
        var itemDivs = $('div.itemDescription');
        for(i=0;i<itemDivs.length;i++)
        {
            $(itemDivs[i]).attr("aria-expanded",false);
        }
        var resetBox = itemDivs;
        //when user clicks link, have the benefit text appear if hidden and hide if shown.
        $('h3.itemHeader').click(function(){
            var theDiv = $(this).closest('div.itemDescription');
            var itemContent = theDiv.children().not('h3');
            itemContent.show();
            $(this).addClass('expanded');

            //when expanded, set ARIA expanded to true; Set to FALSE when not expanded.
            if($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
            {
                $(this).parent().attr("aria-expanded",true);
                //remove class from h3
                $(this).removeClass('itemHeader');
                //unbind to stop further clicks on h3
                //$(this).unbind('click');
                theDiv.parent().removeClass('itemBox');
                theDiv.prevAll().hide();
                theDiv.nextAll().hide();

            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')==false)
            {
                $(this).parent().attr("aria-expanded",false);
                $(this).removeClass('expanded');

            }
        })//end click.

        // next button functionality
        $('a.btn-next').click(function(){


            //hide current div
            $(this).parents('div.itemDescription').hide();

            //assign variable to next header and show
            var nextItem = $(this).parents('div.itemDescription').next();


                nextItem.show();
                //expand contents of next div
                nextItem.attr("aria-expanded",true);
                nextItem.children('h3').removeClass('itemHeader');

                nextItem.children().show();

        })//end next click

        $('a.btn-prev').click(function(){

            //hide current div
            $(this).parents('div.itemDescription').hide();

            //assign variable to next header and show
            var prevItem = $(this).parents('div.itemDescription').prev();
            prevItem.show();

            //expand contents of next div
            prevItem.attr("aria-expanded",true);
            prevItem.children('h3').removeClass('itemHeader');

            prevItem.children().show();

        })//end prev click
</script>
<style>
.itemBox {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 2em;
}
.itemHeader {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="itemBox">
<div class="itemDescription">
    <h3 class="itemHeader" tabindex="0">Header 1</h3>
    <div class="itemText">
        Text
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    </div><!-- /.itemText -->
</div>
<div class="itemDescription">
    <h3 class="itemHeader" tabindex="0">Header 2</h3>
    <div class="itemText">
        Text
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    </div><!-- /.itemText -->
</div>
<div class="itemDescription">
    <h3 class="itemHeader" tabindex="0">Header 3</h3>
    <div class="itemText">
        Text
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    </div><!-- /.itemText -->
</div>
<div class="itemDescription">
    <h3 class="itemHeader" tabindex="0">Header 4</h3>
    <div class="itemText">
        Text
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    </div><!-- /.itemText -->
</div>
<div class="itemDescription">
    <h3 class="itemHeader" tabindex="0">Header 5</h3>
    <div class="itemText">
        Text
        <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    </div><!-- /.itemText -->
</div>
</div><!-- /.itemBox -->
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you just want help debugging your script?

Comment: Usually you'd determine the number of items in the list ahead of time and have some simple if/then logic on this condition.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is if there is a next() or not

This should work

```
    var nextItem = $(this).parents('div.itemDescription').next();
    /* if no length it doesn't exist*/
    if( ! nextItem.length ) {
        nextItem=$(this).parents('div.itemDescription:first')
    }
```

Not part of issue but this loop is not needed

```
  var itemDivs = $('div.itemDescription');
    for(i=0;i<itemDivs.length;i++)
    {
        $(itemDivs[i]).attr("aria-expanded",false);
    }
```

jQuery will handle same thing with:

```
 var itemDivs = $('div.itemDescription').attr("aria-expanded",false);
```

Comment: thank you so much! It worked using your suggestion modifying to: